# Mysql JOIN query apparently slow

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join, query-performance

I have 2 tables. The first, called *stazioni*, where I store live weather data from some weather station, and the second called *archivio2*, where are stored archived day data. The two tables have in common the ID station data (ID on stazioni, IDStazione on archvio2).

*stazioni* (1,743 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `stazioni` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `localita` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `regione` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `altitudine` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `stazione` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `schermo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `installazione` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ubicazione` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `immagine` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lat` double NOT NULL,
  `longi` double NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `temperatura` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `umidita` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressione` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vento` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vento_direzione` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raffica` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pioggia` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minima` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `massima` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orario` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `online` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tipo` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `webcam` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `webcam2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `condizioni` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data2` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

*archivio2* (2,127,347 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `archivio2` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `IDStazione` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `localita` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `temp_media` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_minima` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_massima` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pioggia` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressione` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vento` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raffica` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `records` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data2` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The indexes that I set

```
-- Indexes for table `archivio2`
--
ALTER TABLE `archivio2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `IDStazione` (`IDStazione`),
  ADD KEY `Data2` (`Data2`);

-- Indexes for table `stazioni`
--
ALTER TABLE `stazioni`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `Tipo` (`Tipo`);
ALTER TABLE `stazioni` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `localita` (`localita`);
```

On a map, I call by a calendar the date to search data on archive2 table, by this INNER JOIN query (I put an example date):

```
SELECT *, c.pioggia AS rain, c.raffica AS raff, c.vento AS wind, c.pressione AS press
FROM stazioni as o
INNER JOIN archivio2 as c ON o.ID = c.IDStazione
WHERE c.Data2 LIKE '2019-01-01%'
```

All works fine, but the time needed to show result are really slow (4/5 seconds), even if the query execution time seems to be ok (about 0.5s/1.0s).
I tried to execute the query on PHPMyadmin, and the results are the same. Execution time quickly, but time to show result extremely slow.

EXPLAIN query result

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys       key         key_len ref                 rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      o       ALL     PRIMARY,ID          NULL        NULL    NULL                1743    NULL    
1   SIMPLE      c       ref     IDStazione,Data2    IDStazione  4       sccavzuq_rete.o.ID  1141    Using where
```

---

**UPDATE**: the query goes fine if I remove the index from 'IDStazione'. But in this way I lost all advantages and speed on other queries... why only that query become slow if I put index on that field?

Comment: how many rows  resulting from  the query??

Comment: you can use EXPLAIN to check how exactly query executing(its help to identify its using index or not ) more details - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan

Comment: I have add the EXPLAIN results. Sorry, I have missed it. ;)

Comment: This seems to be more a PHP issue than a MySQL issue, because of your remark "if the query execution time seems to be ok (about 0.5s/1.0s)". you have to determine what is taking 4 seconds to complete the page, and it does not seem to be MySQL

Comment: A good tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: @Luuk as I said, I tried to execute query in PhpMyadmin, but thinkg doesn't changed. :(

Comment: @Strawberry I know, but I need to extract almost the tables content from that query. I tried to select only the fileds needed, but with the same results.

Comment: Still, it's a much better place from which to start

Comment: Fetching the records from today (18/05/2019) is also slow, and there seems to be no data  on this date.  Other option might be does ANALYZE TABLE improve results?

Comment: @Luuk the data for current day are not in the archive. The archive start from the previous day. ;)

Comment: UPDATE: the query goes fine if I remove the index from 'IDStazione'. But in this way I lost all advantages and speed on other queries... why only that query become slow if I put index on that field?

Comment: OK, my comment that selecting today was also slow should have made me think harder. The conclusion ('no index used') as @Paul mentioned was too obvious ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your WHERE clause

```
WHERE c.Data2 LIKE '2019-01-01%'
```

the value of `Data2` must be casted to a string. No index can be used for that condition.

Change it to

```
WHERE c.Data2 >= '2019-01-01' AND c.Data2 < '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This way the engine should be able to use the index on `(Data2)`.

Now check the EXPLAIN result. I would expect, that the table order is swapped and the `key` column will show `Data2` (for `c`) and `ID` (for `o`).

Comment: Thank you Paul! It works!!! You saved me! The EXPLAIN result is exactely as you expect. ;)

Answer (score 1):

(Fixing the DATE is the main performance solution; here is a less critical issue.)

The tables are much bigger than necessary.  Size impacts disk space and, to some extent, speed.

You have 1743 stations, yet the datatype is a 32-bit (4-byte) number (`INT`).  `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` would allow for 64K stations and use only 2 bytes.

Does it get really, really, hot there?  Like 999999999.9 degrees?  `DECIMAL(10.1)` takes 5 bytes; `DECIMAL(4,1)` takes only 3 and allows up to 999.9 degrees.  `DECIMAL(3,1)` has a max of 99.9 and takes only 2 bytes.

What is "`localita` varchar(100)" doing in the big table?  Seems like you could `JOIN` to the stations table when you need it?  Removing that might cut the table size in half.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Rick! I will apply your tips to reduce data and optimize more the DB.
About 'localita', this is the name of locations. I need to repeat it in both table for other application (graphs, table), without made a JOIN every time.